# How to set data in localStorage by Crawlee Puppeteer? In my case it return Access is denied

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, crawlee

I'm using [Crawlee](https://crawlee.dev/) with *Puppeteer*. I want set data in `localStorage` of related `page`. So I used the following code

```
preNavigationHooks: [
    async (crawlingContext,) => {

      const { page, request } = crawlingContext;

      const localStorage = await page.evaluate(() =>

        window.localStorage.setItem(
          'token',
          '8582ce8ff5ae52d5f93a64c08152c87858582ce85f93a640e0827d',
        ),
      );
```

But it return this error (Access is denied):

> DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document